# Trying to create Whatsapps quick reply for pre N phones

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a small window to open if you click on the quick reply button on a notification. In WhatsApp it opens up a half screen window. Currently I am doing the following:

I open up an activity called `NotificationActivity`. In `AndroidManifest.xml` I registered the activity as a

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.NotificationActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.custom"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

This is the style:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.custom">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Now when the app is complete closed (closed and then swiped away) it works perfectly.

However if the app is just minimized, when someone clicks on the reply button it opens up the app and then pastes the NotificationActivity over it.  How do I prevent the app from being opened in the background and only have the half screen notification activity opened.

Thanks so much

Edit:  I was thinking that maybe the xml file was relevant?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:weightSum="20">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lvChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stackFromBottom="false"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatFooter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ECEFF1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sendLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width='0dp'
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8">

                    <com.heyjude.heyjudeapp.customview.EditRobotoRegular
                        android:id="@+id/editChatMsg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/linear_back"
                        android:hint="Type your message..."
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|text"
                        android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                        android:textColor="#5f6060"
                        android:textColorHint="#5f6060"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ivSend"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_icon"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/grey_list"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_22"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_22"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also not sure if this is relevant but here is how I create the reply

```
String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";
String replyLabel = "Type here";
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.REQUEST_ID, messageData.taskid);
intent.putExtra(Constants.JUDE_ID, messageData.from);
intent.putExtra(Constants.FROM, Constants.NOTIFICATION);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
        .setLabel(replyLabel)
        .build();

NotificationCompat.Action replyAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                R.drawable.send_button,
                "Reply", pendingIntent)
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();

builder.addAction(replyAction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need use the attribute [`android:launchMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) with the value `singleInstance`:

> Same as `"singleTask"`, except that the system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always
>   the single and only member of its task.

You should also add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to exclude your activity from the list of recently used applications as explained by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude):

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That
>   is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this
>   attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of
>   recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list;
>   set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

To summarize you need to change your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.NotificationActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.custom"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To start a **special activity** from notification as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse),

> For this situation, set up the `PendingIntent` to start in a fresh
>   task. There's no need to create a back stack, though, because the
>   started Activity isn't part of the application's activity flow.
>   Clicking Back will still take the user to the Home screen.

A special Activity doesn't need a back stack, so you don't have to define its Activity hierarchy in the manifest, and you don't have to call `addParentStack()` to build a back stack. Instead, use the manifest to set up the Activity task options, and create the `PendingIntent` by calling `getActivity()`:

1. In your **manifest**, add the following attributes to the

   > element for the Activity
   >
   > ```
   > android:name="activityclass"
   > ```
   >
   > *The activity's fully-qualified class name.*
   >
   > ```
   > android:taskAffinity=""
   > ```
   >
   > *Combined with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag that you set in code, this ensures that this Activity doesn't go into the application's
   >   default task. Any existing tasks that have the application's default
   >   affinity are not affected.*
   >
   > ```
   > android:excludeFromRecents="true"
   > ```
   >
   > *Excludes the new task from Recents, so that the user can't accidentally navigate back to it.*

Code snippet

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.custom"
...
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

2. Build and issue the notification.(Though you are doing this already I suggest just check it):

   - Create an Intent that starts the Activity.
   - Set the Activity to start in a new, empty task by calling `setFlags()` with the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`.
   - Set any other options you need for the Intent.
   - Create a `PendingIntent` from the Intent by calling `getActivity()`. You can then use this *PendingIntent* as the argument to `setContentIntent()`.

Code snippet.

```
// Instantiate a Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
// Creates an Intent for the Activity
Intent notifyIntent =
        new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// Creates the PendingIntent
PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

// Puts the PendingIntent into the notification builder
builder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
// Notifications are issued by sending them to the
// NotificationManager system service.
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds an anonymous Notification object from the builder, and
// passes it to the NotificationManager
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Also check this official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ExtendedNotification) if required.

Hope this will help you.